# Retrofit GET Query converts equalTo (=) to \u003d

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I have a GET api of

`http://xxxxx/Status?taxYear=2017`

**response =** "IsValid": true

But the Retrofit Query is converting the URL to

`http://xxxxx/Status?taxYear\u003d2017`

**response =** "IsValid": false

This makes the wrong API response. I tried Querymap and all, Help me out.

Comment: @GET("/Status")

methodName(@Query(“taxYear”) String year)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use query in Retrofit endpoints. You have to use the query annotation  like this ...

```
methodName(@Query(encoded = true, value = "taxYear") String filter)
```

Maybe the "encoded" parameter can be false or removed (false is default value).

Comment: its doing same thing. response have to be "IsValid": true but come as "IsValid": false

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify query parameters in the URL.

```
@GET("xxxxx/Status?taxYear=2017") 
Call<ResponseBody> methodName();
```

or other way is :

```
@GET("xxxxx/Status?taxYear={year}")
Call<ResponseBody> methodName(@Path("year") String year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define base URL like

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://xxxxx/";
```

If you define an interface for calling request than try this

```
@GET("Status")
Call<YourModelClass> yourRequestMethodName(@Query("taxYear") String yourYear);
```

Call the above define method like

```
Call<YourModelClass> call = yourRetrofitClientName.yourRequestMethodName("2017");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<YourModelClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<YourModelClass> call, Response<YourModelClass> response) {

                //Handle your response here
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<YourModelClass> call, Throwable t) {
               //Handle your error here
            }
        });
```